# laravel 5.2 project not running without adding index.php on url

Tags: php, laravel

Hello Everyone I am working on my project which in on Laravel 5.2. I have setup my project on my local machine but its now working without adding index.php in url.

I request with the url :-

```
http://localhost/project_folder/admin
```

While I am trying to run without index.php and run my url it gives me following error.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /project_folder/admin was not found on this server.
```

For this I did following steps :
1) Give permission (777) to storage and cache folder.
2) I Go to path /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and edit it, now it look something like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

<Directory /var/www/html>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

In my .htaccess file have following code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /moduleTesting/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Please suggest me if I forget any requirement or anything else.

Comment: There is no `DirectoryIndex index.php` in your apache config. Apache doesn't know what the default file is that it should open when there is no file provided by the URL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable mod\_rewrite for Apache 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Comment: Did you start apache services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please enable mode rewrite.
Please ensure that you have mod rewrite enable on your system.(search for mod_rewrite in info.php having code)

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

in terminal run command:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```